# Deserializaion from Xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

My error is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to type

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
XmlSerializer s1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xdoc.toString()));
```

where xdoc has this value:

```
<root>
  <row1>
    <ing>john</ing>
  </row1>
  <row1>
    <ing>some name</ing>
  </row1>
  <row>
    <name>salad</name>
    <ID>8</ID>
  </row>
</root>
```

I created a class which like this:

```
class Print {
    List<row1> row1 = new List<row1>();
    List<row> row = new List<row>();
}

public class row1
{
    public string ing { get; set; }
}

public class row
{
    public string name { get; set; }       
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not stated the question completely. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to type ... ?

Comment: `typeof(xdoc.toString())` is not C# code. please show real code.

Comment: Well, technically it could be, though I assume the OP meant xdoc.ToString(), which is still odd (just returns constant type string).

Comment: typeof() doesn't take string but type.

Comment: Oh, right, OP fooled me. I was thinking it would do what the GetType() method does.

Comment: well, I had to check it in VS first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need XmlSerializer when you have XDocument. Linq is enough

```
List<row1> row1 = xDoc.Descendants("row1")
                .Select(x => new row1() { ing = x.Element("ing").Value })
                .ToList();

List<row> row = xDoc.Descendants("row")
                    .Select(x => new row() { 
                        name = x.Element("name").Value,
                        ID = x.Element("ID").Value 
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `XmlSerializer` constructor, you need to pass in the type that you are serializing from or deserializing to, not the value. If you are trying to deserialize to a `Print` object, then you need to pass in `typeof(Print)`.

Also, as the code stands now, deserialization will not work, because the `XmlSerializer` class is expecting the root node to be `Print`. To fix this, you can decorate your `Print` class with an `XmlRoot` attribute and pass in the value of `root`. Then your code will likely work.

**Edit:**
Your code will not work, your XML will need an additional element to represent the list:

```
<root>
  <ListOfrow1>
    <row1>...</row1>
  </ListOfrow1>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Furqan that the question is incomplete but the argument to XmlSerializer should be the type of CLR object and not the XDocument. I think it should be something like

```
XmlSerializer s1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Print));
Print = (Print)s1.Deserialize(xdoc);
```

Comment: `Deserialize` takes a stream parameter not XDocument.

Comment: @L.B you are correct. This more pseudo than real code. If the data is already in an XDocument object you can pass xdoc.CreateReader(). It may be the case that the data is in some other form and an XDocument wouldn't need to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The `new XmlSerializer(typeof(xdoc.toString()));` looks like attempt to write `new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));` which is unlikely what you want. You probably want something like `XmlSerializer(typeof(Print))`. Sample can be found in [MSDN - XmlSerializer articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: @Aleks, please follow MSDN's sample. And please try to never post "doesn't work" as comment or part of question - show what, where and how fails + maybe what you expected.